# CSS, HTML – scroll bar problem on smartphone

Tags: html, css, mobile

I have a problem with my site, particularly when I open it from my smartphone.

The problem is that the scroll bar does not make me go up and cuts a part of my container, as you can see, the word REGISTER is very attached to the browser bar. Here's the picture: [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjQqF.jpg)

On the computer this problem is not there, as you can see, there is a padding between the title and the container: [screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r3oLf.png)

Please help me if anyone has the idea of ​​how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

**add this in your template style or after your style**

```
    <style>
           *{
               overflow-y :scroll;
            }
    </style>
```

i hope it was useful